# How can I drag 2 points inverted in Sketch?

Tags: vector, sketch-app, drawing, anchor-point

I want to take 2 points of the object I'm creating in vector mode and drag them in an inverted fashion, so the distance from the center to the 2 points stays the same. This would allow me to create icons that are highly symmetrical without moving both sides individually with lots of error.

My rectangle before dragging points. I selected both the left and right points and dragged the right one towards the right:
[image]
Actual Behavior where both points move to the right:
[image]
Desired behavior where the points move in opposite directions around the center (but would be perfectly symmetrical):
[image]

(I also don't know how to do this while transforming either, so that would be just resizing around a center anchor point)

Comment: I suggest you post some screen shots. It's almost impossible to answer such questions without seeing examples.

Comment: @BillyKerr Ok I added some screenshots to better explain my point.

Comment: Can you scale the selection?

Comment: I **do not** know Sketch. In Illustrator you'd select both points, then hold the `Option` key down and drag Bounding box handles... both points would move with the Bounding Box but other anchors would stay in place.

Comment: It's possible there is a better way to do this now since it's bee a while, but just in case there isn't one: Select 1 point and move it using arrow keys while holding down the Shift key. Then do the same for the other point. When you hold down shift you shouldn't have to press the arrow key more than maybe 4-6 times (in this situation) so it should be easy enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Msorry! Can't be done.
Maybe:

- cut the shape in half
- edit the shape as desired
- duplicate it
- Flip one shape
- Re-connect both