# How to move two anchor points in different directions in sketchapp at once?

Tags: sketch-app

[image]
[image]
I want to skew the Rect from both left and right in the same time, all i know is to select one anchor point at a time and move it as the two anchors needed to be moved in different directions, how could i do this in the same time in sketch-app?

Comment: is it the bottom anchors? what is the final shape you want to obtain? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: The final shape i want to obtain is what you already have seen in the image.

My question is how to move the bottom anchors both in the same time and in different direction after selecting them both to create this shape.

if this still confusing to you.. watch from moment 4:20 here, how to apply this in sketch?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMxHy_N7-LU

Comment: possible duplicate of https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95004/how-can-i-drag-2-points-inverted-in-sketch?rq=1

Comment: That would be a nice feature (move towards eachother)

Comment: But i've seen someone already did this in a video tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMxHy_N7-LU

Answer (score 2):

## Good News!

You can totally do this with the Transform tool.

[image: Transform tool stretching and shrinking a rectangle as if it had perspective]

### Three Ways to Transform

Depending if you're the type of person who likes to click into menus, use the keyboard, or use the toolbar, there's a way to do this.

#### Option 1 and 2

The first way is to go through the `Layer` in the Menu bar, then `Transform > Transform`. For the second option, notice it has a shortcut command too

[image: Layer > Transform > Transform]

#### Option 3

The second is through the Toolbar. If it's been removed, it's easy enough to add it back in by right clicking the Toolbar, selection `Customize Toolbar…` and dragging it where you'd like.

[image: Right clicking the menu on Toolbar to get the Customize Toolbar option]

[image: Highlighting where Transform is in the Customize Toolbar drawer]